# How to make the line smoother with Path in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When the user touches the screen, it will record the gesture as `CGPoint` and then display them with Path. But now the line is not smooth at the turning point. What should I do?

This is my code:

```
struct LineView: View {
    @State var removeLine = false
    @State var singleLineData = [CGPoint]()
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .opacity(0.1)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 4, x: 0, y: 2)
            
            Path { path in
                path.addLines(singleLineData)
            }
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        }
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { state in
                    if removeLine {
                        singleLineData.removeAll()
                        removeLine = false
                    }
                    
                    singleLineData.append(state.location)
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    removeLine = true
                }
        )
        .frame(width: 370, height: 500)
    }
}

struct LineView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LineView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm back and I know a solution to make line smoother.

First I created a class to return Path *「PS: I learned this from Mrs. Karin Prater's youtube course("How to make a drawing app with SwiftUI 3"), Shoutout to her」*

```
class DrawingEngine {
    func createPath(for points: [CGPoint]) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        
        if let firstPoint = points.first {
            path.move(to: firstPoint)
        }
        
        for index in 1..<points.count {
            let mid = calculateMidPoint(points[index-1], points[index])
            
            path.addQuadCurve(to: mid, control: points[index - 1])
        }
        
        if let last = points.last {
            path.addLine(to: last)
        }
                
        return path
    }
    
    func calculateMidPoint(_ p1: CGPoint, _ p2: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let newMidPoint = CGPoint(x: (p1.x+p2.x)/2, y: (p1.y+p2.y)/2)
        return newMidPoint
    }
}
```

Then I only record new state points whose linear distance from the previous point exceeds a certain value(10 or 20...)

```
.gesture(DragGesture()
            .onChanged { state in
                
                if removeLine {
                    removeLine = false
                    singleLineData = [CGPoint]()
                }
                var exceedsMinimumDistance: Bool {
                    return sqrt(pow((singleLineData[singleLineData.count-1].x - state.location.x), 2) + pow((singleLineData[singleLineData.count-1].y - state.location.y), 2)) > 20
                }
                
                if singleLineData.count == 0 {
                    singleLineData.append(state.location)
                } else if exceedsMinimumDistance {
                    singleLineData.append(state.location)
                }
                
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                removeLine = true
            })
```

This is full code of LineView:

```
struct LineView: View {
    @State var removeLine = false
    @State var singleLineData = [CGPoint]()
    let engine = DrawingEngine()
    let minimumDistance: CGFloat = 20
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .opacity(0.1)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 4, x: 0, y: 2)
            
            if singleLineData.count != 0 {
                Path { path in
                    path = engine.createPath(for: singleLineData)
                }
                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            }
            
        }
        .gesture(DragGesture()
            .onChanged { state in
                
                if removeLine {
                    removeLine = false
                    singleLineData = [CGPoint]()
                }
                var exceedsMinimumDistance: Bool {
                    return sqrt(pow((singleLineData[singleLineData.count-1].x - state.location.x), 2) + pow((singleLineData[singleLineData.count-1].y - state.location.y), 2)) > minimumDistance
                }
                
                if singleLineData.count == 0 {
                    singleLineData.append(state.location)
                } else if exceedsMinimumDistance {
                    singleLineData.append(state.location)
                }
                
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                removeLine = true
            })
    }
}
```

My English is not good, hope this solution could help you ;)